# Is there a way to open multiple links one by one into newtabs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, javascript-framework

I need to open 5 or 6 new pages into seperate tabs through one click .
 Is it Possible to do it through javascript that works on all browsers.

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the new link is opened in a new tab or in a new window is handled by the user settings in the browser, so I do not think you can handle this in JavaScript.

Look for `window.open` to open 5 or 6 new windows.